# when I click on run app the android service disappears, also when the app crashing

Tags: android

The onDestroy method of service no is called when the app crashin o I click en run app on Android Studio, because I say that disappears instead of destroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("onDestroy", "service off");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void onDestroy() {
     finish();
     Log.e("onDestroy", "service off");

 }
```

The onDestroy method is used to terminate threads or background processes started in onCreate(). Should not be used for cleaning up and saving data since it
is unreliable(not always called).

Your activity is destroyed when:

- You programmatically call finish()
- User presses the back button

Your activity is destroyed and recreated if:

- User rotates the device
- User changes language
- The application is terminated by the system to regain RAM

The saved data that the system uses to restore the previous state is called the "instance state" and is a collection of key-value pairs stored in
a Bundle object.

By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save information about each View object in your activity layout (such as the text
value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is restored to its
previous state with no code required by you.

Comment: When the activity from which the service is launched is destroyed, does the service also do it?

Comment: Yes, onDestroy is used to terminate threads or background processes - services.